# Cannot install SQL Server 2008 on Windows 7?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to install SQL server 2008 in my computer.  It's running 32 bit, Windows 7.  However, after a couple of steps, when I reach the point where the installation is showing that it's arriving in "support files of installation", then the setup modal window disapears and does not proceed with the installation.

Does anyone have a clue of why this could be happening?

Are there any tools that need to be pre-installed: frame work or some other tool in order for this to work?

Comment: I'm voting to close this as OT.  Try Google for this.  http://www.sqlserverclub.com/essentialguides/how-to-install-sql-server-2008-step-by-step-guide.aspx

Comment: Do you have visual studio installed ? If so which version ? Also do you have a light version of sql installed already ? Express or something...

Comment: ive checked google... dirent get much help. my issue seems to be more complicated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to completely remove all versions of SQL server.

Guide: http://developerscentral.net/2011/remove-sql-server-2008-r2-completely/

And try again.